# Invalid preprocessing directive #\ when compiling/linking with NVCC

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker, linker-errors, nvcc

I have a large codebase to which I am trying to add GPU computing via RAJA. Currently I am seeing

```
main.o:24:16: error: invalid preprocessing directive #\
```

How do I probe this for information as to where this error might be coming from?

Compiler:

```
.../cuda-10.1.243/bin/nvcc
```

Relevant flags:

```
CXX = /usr/tce/packages/cuda/cuda-10.1.243/bin/nvcc
LINK = time $(CXX) -std=c++11 \
-DENABLE_RAJA \
-DENABLE_CUDA=On \
-DENABLE_OPENMP=Off \
--expt-extended-lambda \
-x cu \
-arch=sm_70 \
```

I have used the command

```
grep -r --include=\*.h --include=\*.cpp --include=\*.o '#\\' *
```

To search for where this issue might be coming from but I didn't get any hits.

Here is are some examples of the output of Make (abbreviated)

```
time /usr/tce/packages/cuda/cuda-10.1.243/bin/nvcc -std=c++11 -DENABLE_RAJA -DENABLE_CUDA=On -DENABLE_OPENMP=Off --expt-extended-lambda -x cu -arch=sm_70  -c -I/includestuff  main.cpp -o main.o 

time /usr/tce/packages/cuda/cuda-10.1.243/bin/nvcc -std=c++11 -DENABLE_RAJA -DENABLE_CUDA=On -DENABLE_OPENMP=Off --expt-extended-lambda -x cu -arch=sm_70  -c -I/includestuff   /somepath/Funcs.cpp -o /somepath/Funcs.o 

......some other lines like the one above.....

time /usr/tce/packages/cuda/cuda-10.1.243/bin/nvcc -std=c++11 -DENABLE_RAJA -DENABLE_CUDA=On -DENABLE_OPENMP=Off --expt-extended-lambda -x cu -arch=sm_70  main.o ~GIANT LIST OF .o FILES~  -o prog.exe
```

Comment: "main.o:24:16:" *is* a hint.

Comment: When I try to look at main.o,  it is just a bunch of jibberish.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: For whatever reason, the compiler is being asked to **compile** main.o. That's wrong; main.o is generated when you compile main.c or main.cpp. You need to **link** it into your executable, so its name might be mentioned, but it's being handled wrong.

Comment: @InfiniteElementMethod `main.o` is not gibberish. It's an object file compiled from some source file. Tools exist to disassemble and inspect it. Read up on `nm`, `objdump`, `readelf` (and more). But, in any case, as @Peter points out, the problem here seems to be that you are trying to pass an object file to the compiler *as if* it was a source file.